# I try to use validation query but doesn't work

Tags: jquery-plugins

Here is the header

--

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
 href="http://jquery-validatation-engine-extended.googlecode.com/files    
 /validationEngine.jquery.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-validatation-engine-  
 extended.googlecode.com/files/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-validatation-engine-  
 extended.googlecode.com/files/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
```

### here is the js to initialize jquery

```
    $("#formID").validationEngine({   /* create the form validation */
        inlineValidation: false,
        promptPosition: "centerRight",
        success :  function(){use_ajax=true},   /* if everything is OK enable AJAX     */
               failure : function(){use_ajax=false}    /* in case of validation    failure disable AJAX */
     })
```

### here is the form in html

```
 <form name=formID method=post action=devenir_membre2.php>
 <table width=85%  cellspacing=1>
  <tr><td width=50% style="padding-bottom: 15px;">Nickname:</td>
 <td width=50%>   <input type=text class="validate[required]" name=nickname></td></tr>
</table>
 </form>
```

What could I do ?

Regards, thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Assign a correct id to the HTML form, that is :

```
<form id="formId" name="...." ...
```